# Check value of XML attribute

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3

Not sure how I would check to see if the value of a nodes attribute "action" is equal to "left". My XML looks like the following:

```
    <track timestamp="18/05/2011 13:21:49-0400" id="3" action="track">
               <coordinates> test 1</coordinates>
    </track>
    <track timestamp="18/05/2011 13:21:49-0400" id="3" action="track">
               <coordinates> test 1</coordinates>
    </track>
    <track timestamp="18/05/2011 13:21:49-0400" id="3" action="left">
                <coordinates> test 1</coordinates>
    </track>
    <track timestamp="18/05/2011 13:21:49-0400" id="3" action="track">
        <coordinates> test 1</coordinates>
    </track>
```

I guess I need to loop through the xml data and check and if its true start my function. This is what I have so far:

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("get_data.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

               function processXML(e:Event):void {

            myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

                            for (var i:int = 0; i<myXML.*.length(); i++){
                                 if (myXML.tracking[i].action == "left")
                                    {
                                         start_animation();
                                    }
                            };
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just select all the nodes with a certain value like this:

```
node.(@attribute == "value")
```

As an example, this will only output the nodes where `side` is set as `"left"`:

```
var xml:XML = 
<list>
    <node side="left">hi</node>
    <node side="left">there</node>
    <node side="right">marty</node>
</list>;

trace(xml.node.(@side == "left"));
```

Output:

```
<node side="left">hi</node>
<node side="left">there</node>
```

You can assign this to an XMLList like so:

```
var list:XMLList = xml.node.(@side == "left");
```

And then iterate through as you normally would:

```
var i:XML;
for each(i in list)
{
    trace(i);
}
```

---

In response to your comment question:

You can use the `length()` property to yield how many nodes were found with their side set as left, like so:

```
var xml:XML = 
<list>
    <node side="left">hi</node>
    <node side="left">there</node>
    <node side="right">marty</node>
</list>;

var list:XMLList = xml.node.(@side == "left");

// check if a node was found
if(list.length() > 0)
{
    doStuff();
}

function doStuff():void
{
    trace("a node had its side set as left");
}
```

Comment: this is great! do you recommend any online resources for as3/xml?

Comment: can I do something like total = count(xml.node.(@side == "left")); if (count != 0){ do my function}  (php)

Comment: Thanks! This is the one that I used a loong time ago: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/using_xml_as3_pg1.htm

Comment: again thanks for your response. You will have to excuse me if I still have another questions. Your code above will show the data if "left" is set but no action is taken if it is. Is this possible?

Comment: So I really dont need any other info from the XML other then call a function (only once) if anywhere in the XML left is present. Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: You can use length() to see how many nodes were found, and call a function if more than 0 were found. See my updated answer.